# R Plotly Animation Gapminder

Tags: r, animation, plotly, bubble-chart

I was wondering if is it possible to add annotations to a Plotly Animated Gapminder plot? I mean, I don't need that all the bubbles have annotations, but I would like that some of them had.

Here's an example, the only country that I want to display the name is China.

```
library(plotly)
library(gapminder)


m <- gapminder[gapminder$country == "China", ]

a <- list(
  x = m$gdpPercap,
  y = m$lifeExp,
  text = m$country,
  xref = "x",
  yref = "y",
  showarrow = TRUE,
  arrowhead = 7,
  ax = 20,
  ay = -40
)

df <- gapminder 
fig <- df %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~gdpPercap, 
    y = ~lifeExp, 
    size = ~pop, 
    color = ~continent, 
    frame = ~year, 
    text = ~country, 
    hoverinfo = "text",
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers'
  ) %>% add_markers() %>% layout(annotations = a)
```

I need that the annotation to follow the China marker. Do you know if this is possible?

Thanks!
Bruno